# Create new column on basis of another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in Dataframe by the name STATUS, which contains value "AMEND ORDER" or it is empty. I need to create a FLAG on the basis of that column, if it values contains **AMEND** word in the value, set FLAG 1, or 0. I am trying to use the below code but it errors it.

```
t[t['STATUS'].str.contains('AMEND')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If empty are missing values or `None`s chain another mask by `|` for bitwise `OR` and cast to integers for `True -> 1, False - > 0` mapping:

```
t['FLAG'] = (t['STATUS'].str.contains('AMEND') | t['STATUS'].isna()).astype(int)
```

If empty is empty string compare values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
t['FLAG'] = (t['STATUS'].str.contains('AMEND') | t['STATUS'].eq('')).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be one way to do it

```
mydat.loc[mydat['Status']=="",'flag']=0
mydat.loc[mydat['Status']=="AMEND ORDER",'flag']=1
```

Status       flag

0   AMEND ORDER 1.0

1   AMEND ORDER 1.0

2. "............." 0.0

3   AMEND ORDER 1.0

4   ".............." 0.0